# Change background image of Shape by clicking on Shape

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, case, shapes

I'm looking for VBA code that will cycle through background images (saved on my computer) shown within a Shape by clicking on the Shape.

I found two sets of code that give me a good start but I can't figure out how to merge the code to get the result I'm looking for.

I want each click on a Shape to keep cycling through the following command:

1. Initial Shape: transparent background
2. Single Click on Shape: Transparent background replaced with BackgroundImage1
3. Another Single Click on Shape: BackgroundImage1 replaced with BackgroundImage2
4. Another Single Click on Shape: BackgroundImage2 replaced with transparent background

I found this code to change color of the Shape by clicking:

```vb
Sub trafficlight()
    Dim WhoAmI As String, sh As Shape
    WhoAmI = Application.Caller
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(WhoAmI).Fill.ForeColor
        Select Case .RGB
            Case vbRed
                .RGB = vbGreen
            Case vbGreen
                .RGB = vbYellow
            Case Else
                .RGB = vbRed
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

And this code to change the Shape with an image saved on my computer:

```vb
Sub Rectangle9_Click()
    Dim WhoAmI As String, sh As Shape
    WhoAmI = Application.Caller
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(WhoAmI).Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture "C:\Users\username\Desktop\BackgroundImage1.png"
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I’ve been working on this for awhile with no luck. I was hoping to hoping to get some help to get me going in the right direction but I guess it was a mistake to reach out for help on this site. I’ll keep digging elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of what image is currently displayed. You could set an `integer` for each time the image changes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeShapePic()
Static i As Integer

With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Fill
    Select Case i
        Case 0
            .UserPicture ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\BackgroundImage1.png")
            i = 1
        Case 1
            .UserPicture ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\BackgroundImage2.png")
            i = 2
        Case 2
            .UserPicture ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\BackgroundImage3.png")
            i = 3
        Case 3
           .Solid
           .Transparency = 0#
            i = 0
    End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the workbook.open. When you dim an integer it's set to zero. Alternatively you could declare a static variable within the procedure rather than a global

Comment: Yes, you are right. Stupid I did not see that... I will edit my answer.

Comment: @HarassedDad Thank you so much!  I had a little trouble initially because the shape was filling with white instead of transparent but I replaced: .Transparency = 1# and it seemed to fix it. You got me out of a jam!

Answer (score 0):

you Can use code : Remove Background image/ Picture as use tool picture format -> set transparent color in excel .

```
 Sub RemoveBackground()
   Dim selectedPicture As Picture
    Set selectedPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 3")
 ' Set the transparent color of the picture
    With selectedPicture.ShapeRange.PictureFormat
        .TransparentBackground = True
        .TransparencyColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With 
End Sub
```

=================

```
    Sub RemoveShapes()
    ' Select the image you want to remove the background from
    Dim selectedImage As Shape
    Set selectedImage = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Image1")     ' Set the transparent color of the image 

    With selectedImage.PictureFormat
        .TransparentBackground = msoTrue
        .TransparencyColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With
  End Sub
```

Thank u